# Can I use @extend (SASS) method to a nested class and get the output without parent class?

Tags: css, sass

**HTML**

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="first"></div>
</div>
<div class="second"></div>
```

**SASS**

```
.main
    background: #eee
    .first
        width: 100px
        height: 100px
        background: green

.second
    @extend .first
```

**Combiled CSS**

```
.main{
    background: #ccc;
}
.main .first, .main .second{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: green;
}
/* Output needed: .main .first, .second{... */
```

The class **.second** is not a child of class **.main**, so is it possible to get the output like **.main .first, .second{...  ?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [placeholder selector](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/placeholder-selectors) and extend it in `.first` and `.second`:

```
%commonStyles
    width: 100px
    height: 100px
    background: green

.main
    background: #eee
    .first
        @extend %commonStyles

.second
    @extend %commonStyles
```